# How to push array into array using php class

Tags: php, arrays

i would like to push some arrays into arrays and save it in a session.
And i tried to do this in a php class. I'm new to that so i made some mistakes and can't help me out.

my `index.php`:

```
<?php 

session_start();
include("./cart.php");

//bezeichnung, preis, attribut
$myOrder = new Cart('17', 0.50, 'Book1');
$myOrder1 = new Cart('18', 1.50, 'Book2');
$_SESSION['products'] = array();
array_push($_SESSION['products'], $myOrder, $myOrder1);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_SESSION['products']);
echo '</pre>';
```

my `cart.php`:

```
<?php

class Cart {
    private $name;
    private $price;
    private $attr;

    public function __construct($name, $price, $attr) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->price = $price;
        $this->attr = $attr;
    }

    public function getName(){
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getPrice(){
        return $this->price;
    }

    public function getAttr(){
        return $this->attr;
    }
}
```

i get something like this:
The part `:Cart:private` is really not good. This should be juest name,price and attr. I think i'm pushing the whole object into the array. How can i avoid this ?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Cart Object
        (
            [name:Cart:private] => 17
            [price:Cart:private] => 0.5
            [attr:Cart:private] => Book1
        )

    [1] => Cart Object
        (
            [name:Cart:private] => 18
            [price:Cart:private] => 1.5
            [attr:Cart:private] => Book2
        )
)
```

Comment: You're pushing objects, not arrays.

Comment: I thought so. Do you have maybe a hint to do it better

Comment: What's wrong with what you're doing? You should be able to do `$_SESSION['products'][$i]->getName()` to access the property.

Comment: You can do a public method in your Cart class that will return all needed properties as an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a public method in your Cart class that will return all needed properties as an array.

```
class Cart {
    private $name;
    private $price;
    private $attr;

    public function __construct($name, $price, $attr) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->price = $price;
        $this->attr = $attr;
    }

    public function getName(){
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getPrice(){
        return $this->price;
    }

    public function getAttr(){
        return $this->attr;
    }

    public function toArray(){
        return array(
            'name' => $this->getName(),
            'price' => $this->getPrice(),
            'attr' => $this->getAttr(),
         );
    }

}
```

Now in your index.php you can do:

```
 array_push($_SESSION['products'], $myOrder->toArray(), $myOrder1->toArray());
```